# Installing TP-Link AC1200 T5E PCIe Adapter on Debian 11

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, debian, wifi-configuration, wifi-driver

There's a lot of info online about how to install the TP-Link AC1200 T4UH version, or similar, but nothing on the T5E as far as I could find.

How do you setup the TP-Link AC1200 T5E PCIe Adapter on Debian 11?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently TP-Link adapters are a major pain to install on Linux, especially on a non-Ubuntu distro. However, the processes was pretty painless for me on Debian 11 (bullseye). Unless you are an experienced user, it might be difficult to figure out how you can set it up, so here's a simple guide for this device. However, these steps should work with other devices.

Note that the device is just an adapter for the actual WiFi card (the little green chip):

[image: wifi card]

The actual WiFi card in my case was an Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265.You'll have much better luck searching for drivers with the actual WiFi card's name rather than the adapter's.

[image: actual card]

### Finding your card

Start by installing hardware info tool [`lshw`](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/lshw) (after inserting the adapter into an empty PCIe slot,of course):

```
sudo apt install lshw
```

Then run

```
lshw -C network
```

It should output something like this:

```
you@yourcomputer:~# lshw -C network
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7265
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 59
       serial: 18:cc:18:ed:3f:73
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                                        pay attention to this
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.14.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 firmware=29.4063824552.0 7265D-29.ucode ip=192.168.1.111 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:29 memory:f7efe000-f7efffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       ...and so on
```

Look for the device matching the one on the adapter; in this case it was the `Wireless 7265` one. Under `configuration` for that device, note that it says `driver=iwlwifi`.

This is the driver you need for this device. It actually might already be installed. To check this, run

```
sudo apt show firmware-iwlwifi
```

Note the `firmware-` prefix; make sure to add it to whatever driver you're searching for.

That should return something like this if it is installed.

```
Package: firmware-iwlwifi
Version: 20210315-3
Priority: optional
Section: non-free/kernel
Source: firmware-nonfree  remember this
Maintainer: Debian Kernel Team <debian-kernel@lists.debian.org>
Installed-Size: 117 MB
Suggests: initramfs-tools
Homepage: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
Tag: admin::hardware, role::app-data, use::driver
Download-Size: 13.4 MB
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/non-free amd64 Packages
Description: Binary firmware for Intel Wireless cards
 This package contains the binary firmware for Intel Wireless cards
 supported by the iwl3945, iwl4965, and iwlwifi drivers.
 .
 Contents:
                     the wifi card is listed here, so you can move on
  * Intel Wireless 7265 firmware, version 25.228.9.0
    (iwlwifi-7265-9.ucode)
  * Intel Wireless 7265 firmware, version 17.bfb58538.0
    (iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode)
  ...and so on
```

If it is installed, make sure your WiFi card is listed in the package description under `Contents`. If it is listed, skip the next step and move on to **Setting up a connection**, if not, or if it wasn't installed at all, make sure to complete the next step.

### Installing the drivers

If the package source doesn't say `nonfree`, you should be able to directly install it with

```
sudo apt install firmware-iwlwifi
```

and move on.

However if it is a `nonfree` package (`nonfree` here is unrelated to payments of any kind; the package is free to download), then because of copyright/patent/licensing issues, it can't be availible for direct download. You'll have to enable downloading packages from `nonfree` sources.

To do this you need to edit the `apt` sources file at `/etc/apt/sources.list`. You can do this in an editor of your choice or through the command line

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Edit these lines by adding `contrib non-free` to the end of them both (the file might look slightly diffrent for you):

```
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 11 _Bullseye_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20211107-12:44]/ bullseye con>

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 11 _Bullseye_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20211107-12:44]/ bullseye cont>

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye main  add "contrib non-free" here (without the quotes)
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye main  also add it here

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main contrib non-free

# bullseye-updates, to get updates before a point release is made;
# see https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html#_updates_and_backports
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye-updates main contrib non-free

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
```

Then save <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> and exit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>. You can run `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` to print the file contents and double check it was saved correctly.

You should now be able to install the driver with

```
sudo apt install firmware-iwlwifi
```

### Setting up a connection

Now that the driver is installed, you can connect to the WiFi. There's a couple ways listed [here](https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse#Automatic), but I think the easiest is using [`connman`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/ConnMan).

Install with

```
sudo apt install connman
```

Open `connman`

```
connmanctl
```

Enable WiFi

```
connmanctl> enable wifi
```

Scan Networks

```
connmanctl> scan wifi
Scan completed for wifi
```

Show networks

```
connmanctl> services 
YOUR_WIFI_NETWORK_NAME   wifi_COPY_THIS_PART_managed_psk
...      ...
```

Connect

```
connmanctl> agent on
Agent registered

connmanctl> connect wifi_COPY_THIS_PART_managed_psk 
Agent RequestInput wifi_COPY_THIS_PART_managed_psk
Passphrase = [ Type=psk, Requirement=mandatory, Alternates=[ WPS ] ]
WPS = [ Type=wpspin, Requirement=alternate ]

Passphrase?  it'll prompt you for your password here
Connected wifi_COPY_THIS_PART_managed_psk
```

Exit

```
connmanctl> quit
```

Your WiFi info will be saved and it'll reconnect automatically on system startup.

Test if it works by unplugging any Ethernet cables so the WiFi card is the only way it could possibly connect to the internet. Then you can ping a random website to see if there's a response. E.g.:

```
you@yourcomputer:~# ping google.com
PING google.com (142.251.45.46) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from dfw25s47-in-f14.1e100.net (142.251.45.46): icmp_seq=1 ttl=115 time=12.8 ms  got some responses, looks like 
64 bytes from dfw25s47-in-f14.1e100.net (142.251.45.46): icmp_seq=2 ttl=115 time=13.7 ms     everything is good.
64 bytes from dfw25s47-in-f14.1e100.net (142.251.45.46): icmp_seq=3 ttl=115 time=13.4 ms
64 bytes from dfw25s47-in-f14.1e100.net (142.251.45.46): icmp_seq=4 ttl=115 time=15.2 ms
64 bytes from dfw25s47-in-f14.1e100.net (142.251.45.46): icmp_seq=5 ttl=115 time=13.3 ms
⚠️ Hit Ctrl-C or it won't stop
```

And you're done.